# Can I configure Cloudfront so its split traffic to two origins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Can I configure Cloudfront so its split traffic to two origins so that the incoming url looks like its all going to one server, but then depending on path go to EB for some requests and S3 for others (dynamic versus static).

Even if I can do this is it a good idea, or should it be obvious from the original request url that the static and dynamic pages are hosted from different location.

Comment: How would the logic know which goes to s3 and which to dynamic?  Can you explain your use case a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can... and if you want to use CloudFront for all of the content, there's no reason that comes to mind why you wouldn't use a single distribution.

As long as you can sensibly specify which path patterns go to which origin, it's pretty straightforward to configure.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern